# Rebase onto merged version of a github merge request

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-rebase

On github.com merge requests from forks don't require to have the source branch be up to date with the branch you want to merge into. You just specify the commit. I very often saw merge requests with additional pipelines attached, including tests. Those require to have a version of the repository with the MRs commits merged to actually test it.

I want to have this merged version locally, so I can test it (e.g. to validate why a test fails). What is the easiest way to get this? The best would be that I just have a branch to rebase my local one onto.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

[image]

You basically create a local branch.